# delegate become nil iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates, protocols

I created a custom UIView with the buttons above , this view opens as a pop- up to a viewcontroller . I want the view controller intercepts the pressure of the buttons so I created a protocol methods but delegates in the view controller is never called.

The protocol:

```
@protocol InsertDelegate <NSObject>

-(void)addNode:(double)x pointY:(double)y radius:(double)r forw:(int)forw;
-(void)cancelView:(UIView*)view;

@end
```

In the AddNewNode.h

```
@interface AddNewNode : UIView 

 @property (assign, nonatomic)id <InsertDelegate> delegate;

 - (IBAction)actionCancel:(id)sender;

 - (IBAction)actionAdd:(id)sender;
 @end
```

In the AddNewNode.m

```
- (IBAction)actionCancel:(id)sender { //this action is connect with storyboard
     NSLog(@"%@", self.delegate);
     //(null)
    [self.delegate cancelView:self];
}

 - (IBAction)actionAdd:(id)sender { //this action is connect with storyboard
     NSLog(@"%@", self.delegate);
     //(null)
   [self.delegate addNode:x pointY:y radius:r forw:f];

 }
```

In ViewController.h:

```
 @interface ViewController : UIViewController <InsertDelegate>
```

In ViewController.m

```
 (IBAction)addNewNode:(id)sender {

       AddNewNode * addRowView =[[AddNewNode alloc]init];

       addRowView.delegate=self;
       [self.view addSubview: addRowView];

 }

 //delegate methods never called
 -(void)addNode:(double)x pointY:(double)y radius:(double)r forw:(int)forw{

 }
 -(void)cancelView:(UIView*)view{

 }
```

In UIView custom self.delegate become null and I don't understand why

Comment: are you using `@synthesize` for your `delegate` ?

Comment: I did it now , but the result is the same , the methods are not called

Comment: Did your IBActions called?! Can you double check it that too?!

Comment: @AliRP That's what im thinking too..

Comment: Yes,  the IBActions are called and works

Comment: @Teodoro which one? the `- (IBAction)actionAdd:(id)sender` or '(IBAction)addNewNode:(id)sender' ?

Comment: All the IBAction are connected and works, in UIView and in ViewController

Comment: `AddNewNode` UIView custom class from storyboard also?

Comment: Yes, is with storyborad

Answer (score 0):

What about making an IBOutlet for your

> ViewController.h

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <InsertDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) AddNewNode * addNewNode;
//or connect IBOutlet of your `addNewNode`
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet (addNewNode);

@end
```

> ViewController.m

```
- (IBAction)addNewNode:(id)sender 
{
    // you dont need to allocate anymore
    self.addRowView.delegate=self;
    // and you need to trigger the delegate from `- (IBAction)actionAdd:(id)sender;`
    [self.addRowView actionAdd:sender];
}
```

Comment: the delegate method is still not called when I click on the button of view

Comment: have you called this `[self.addRowView actionAdd:sender];` ?

Comment: Yes, the delegate method is called during the creation of the view , but not when I need that when I click the button

Comment: In UIView custom self.delegate become null and I don't understand why

Answer (score -1):

try the following

Create a private property to hold the instance

```
@implement AddNewNode()
@propery (nonatomic, strong) AddNewNode * addNewNode;
@end
```

from inside the button handler

```
(IBAction)addNewNode:(id)sender {

   self.addNewNode =[[AddNewNode alloc]init];
   self.addRowView.delegate=self;

}
```

Comment: In UIView custom self.delegate become null and I don't understand why